# How to optimize adding new stock locations in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

When I have a lot of products (3000 and 22000 variants), adding new stock location takes hours because Spree is creating stock items for every variant.

During this time variants table is locked and whole system is unusable. Is there some workaround for this or maybe it was fixed in some new version of Spree?

I am using spree 2.0.3.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are several severe performance issues with creating stock locations related to product/variant/taxon touching. I improved one of them with this pull request, https://github.com/spree/spree/pull/4636 however, there are many many more optimizations that can be made. I don't know of any way to currently make that fast without some hackery (like disabling association touching), a giant SQL statement to create things directly, or spend some significant time improving Spree's performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face the same problem, with >400K variants, it's impossible to add a new stock location. So, I create a script in ruby and for all variants write an insert statement to a `SQL` file. I must create the stock location without propagate_all_variants

```
# lib/create_stock_items.rb

begin
  file = File.open("stock_items.sql", "w")
rescue IOError => e
  puts e
end

file.write("INSERT INTO spree_stock_items (stock_location_id, variant_id, backorderable) VALUES \n")
variants = Spree::Variant.all.pluck(:id)
length = variants.count

variants.each_with_index do |variant, index|
  if index+1 == length
    file.write("(#{stock_location_id}, #{variant}, false); \n")
  else
    file.write("(#{stock_location_id}, #{variant}, false), \n")
  end
end

file.close
```

Then run bundle exec rails runner `lib/create_stock_items.rb -e production`. This will create a `stock_items.sql` file in `Rails` root path, and finally load that `SQL` directly on `BD` (rails dbconsole).

I know it's a little hack, but a very fast solution for me.